# Problems changing the style of certain items in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, coding-style, bold

I have a ListView of TextViews and to highlight one of these, I want to make the TextView **bold**. This only works if I don't scroll the ListView. After I scroll, the boldness changes to a different position. Does anyone know why, or how I can solve this problem?

Comment: this guy solved the problem for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17940890/1331671

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be problem with ListView, because listview reuses view items (and puts content inside them), if you are using convertView feature. It's hard to say without seeing your code where it goes wrong. You could try using Html class to handle the boldness of required items:

```
txt.setText(Html.fromHtml('<b>Text that requires bold</b>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not right offhand. I would recommend posting some code; the problem sounds like it may be in your implementation